# Scrollbar is not working in android device

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I making an app with help of jquery mobile in which I have used cordova 3.1, HTML5,JQuery

I have used scrollbar and it working in browser but in android device and emulator it is not working.
Please suggest me what mistake I have done

In Html5
dynamically creating in js file

```
"<div>" +
    "<textarea id='text' onkeypress='PRESS()' data-theme='c' style='overflow-y:scroll;'></textarea>" +
"</div>"
```

In js file

```
    function PRESS(e)
    {
        var max = 200;


        if ($('#text').val().length == max) {
            return;
              e.preventDefault();
        } else if ($('#text').val().length > max) {
                // Maximum exceeded
            alert("keypress  Maximum exceeded" + $('#text').val().length);
                $('#text').val($('#Special').val().substring(0, max));
            }

    }
```

Comment: Are you want to vertical scroll in textarea?

Comment: @Ved yes I need vertical right scrollbar in the textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add max-height value as you want.

```
<textarea id='text'  data-theme='c' style='max-height: 100px;'></textarea>
```

Comment: scrollbar is not coming

Comment: scrollbar not showing but data scrolling vertical using this css